# Restricting displaycount of a row in sqlite table

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two columns in a table. I am using this table in an android application. For ex., TAB1:

[image]

when I display One, the display_count of 1 should increment by 1. Like that, I have to display the names continuously through out my application. Mean while, the display_count is getting too big in long run. Is there any option in sqlite, to restrict the column data, such that, if I reach a certain value say display_count = 64 for a row, the display_count should should reset to 1 and again start from 1. To say clearly, display_count should not exceed 64.

Comment: Logically while updating, you can use (col=col+1)%65 instead of col=col+1. The thing is count will again start from 0 instead of 1

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @rakeshjain, till now, what I did is some thing like,                                                   `update TAB1 set Display_count = Display_count+1 where Display_count in (select MIN(Display_count) from TAB1);`     According to your suggestion, I should change it to           `update TAB1 set Display_count = (Display_count+1)%64 where Display_count in (select MIN(Display_count) from TAB1);`        Right?

Comment: what is this where condition for?

Comment: shouldn't the where condition be on name='something' where something is what is being displayed out of one,two,three etc.?

Comment: This is always updating a single row. But, what I want is, suppose the displaycount of One increases beyond 64, it should be set to zero, as well as while the next update, the displaycount of Two should be incremented. Like that.

Comment: No no, I want to update the minimum displaycount here. I should not use name in this context.

Comment: @rakeshjain, I have used your answer in another context of my code. please Give your solution as an answer. I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: I have put my solution as answer. You can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically while updating, you can use (col=col+1)%65 instead of col=col+1. The thing is count will again start from 0 instead of 1

Comment: Thank you @rakeshjain for posting the answer. I got it now.